# Place buttons of my own on-screen keyboard

Tags: wpf, xaml

### What do I want?

I want to create my own simple on-screen keyboard using the WPF with MVVM.
I want to place buttons like here:

```
| q | w | e | r | t | y | u | i | o | p | 
|  a  | s | d | f | g | h | j | k |  l  |
|  z  |  x  |  c  | v |  b  |  n  |  m  |
```

Note: the first row contains *10 buttons*, the second row - *8 buttons* and the third row - *7 buttons*.

### View model

In the view model I've created the following `List` of the symbols of the keyboard, that I'll bind in the view.

```
class ViewModel
{ 
    // ...

    public List<char> EnglishKeyboard { get; set; } = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm".ToList();

    // ...
}
```

### View

In the view I am using `ItemsControl` to show the buttons:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding EnglishKeyboard}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <!-- Which panel should I use here? -->
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button FontFamily="Arial"
                    FontSize="24"
                    Content="{Binding}"
            />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

### Question

How can I display my buttons as I showed before? Which panel should I use in the `ItemsPanelTemplate` of the `ItemsControl`?

Comment: I think you will need to implement this yourself, there is no default panel with behavior like this. I would do it with Grid and RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions. Correct widths on column definitions can solve this. But you will probably need to specify which characters are on which row. `List<char>` is not enough. At least `List<List<char>>` is needed, representing a list of character lines.

Comment: view model and itemsControl in this case only complicate matters. 26 buttons defined in xaml should be much simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GregaMohorko said, I should use `List<List<char>>`, that representing a list of character lines.

### View model

```
class ViewModel
{
    // ...

    public ViewModel()
    {
        EnglishKeyboard = new List<List<char>>()
        {
            // Keyboard lines.
            "qwertyuiop".ToList(),
            "asdfghjkl".ToList(),
            "zxcvbnm".ToList()
        };
    }

    public List<char> EnglishKeyboard { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

### View

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding EnglishKeyboard}">
    <!-- Show keyboard lines in the StackPanel -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <!-- Keyboard line -->
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button FontFamily="Arial"
                                FontSize="24"
                                Content="{Binding}"
                        />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**Thanks!**